# How do I name a label in Trello?

Tags: trello

How do I name a label in Trello?  I noticed this was possible in the Trello on Trello board, but can't find the UI to do it.

Comment: it's also possible to view the named labels in the board
http://jsdecorator.com/blog/post/fix-trello-limited-lable-color-issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out, you can click on the label name in board preferences to change the label name.

Comment: For clarity's sake: you get to board preferences by clicking the icon next to the board's name.